# Unable to run C# test unit project using batch command from jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am doing automation using selenium and c#. Everything is running file when I run from visual studio but getting issue in file path then run via jenkins.

**Batch command I am trying :**

```
"nuget.exe" restore UnitTestProject1.sln
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" UnitTestProject1.sln
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll
```

**Output from Jenkins :**

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1
[UnitTestProject1] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins934555759751738078.bat

C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1>"nuget.exe" restore UnitTestProject1.sln 
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.5.180.51428' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.

C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1>"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" UnitTestProject1.sln 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.1055.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 3/5/2018 6:38:36 PM.
Project "C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Project file contains ToolsVersion="15.0". This toolset may be unknown or missing, in which case you may be able to resolve this by installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have been forced to a particular ToolsVersion for policy reasons. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="4.0". For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=291333.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
Skipping target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyAppConfigFile:
Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  UnitTestProject1 -> C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll
Done Building Project "C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.csproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.sln" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.03

C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.27019.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Please specify tests to run, or specify the /publish switch to publish results. 
For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"

C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1>/testcontainer:UnitTestProject1.dll
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\developer\.jenkins\workspace\LinkedinAutomation\UnitTestProject1>exit 123 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems everything is fine till end. It has issue in finding project dll file at end with test container.

Comment: You tagged this as `nunit` but are running MsTest.exe. Either it's tagged wrong or you're running the wrong executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following set as a Windows Batch command:
[image: Windows Batch Command].  This is one long line that runs the individual project Test DLLs of our components.  Each DLL is from a Unit Test Project.

It appears that your command line has forward slashes, and not the Windows directory separator, the backslash.

I have also found that I needed a different command line to get my tests running properly. I had to use the vstest.console.exe to run the tests.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" Application_Tests\bin\Release\Application_Tests.dll AppLib_Tests\bin\Release\AppLib_Tests.dll`

For the full command line: [vstest.console.exe command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/jj155796.aspx)

Comment: Hey your given command run for me perfectly. Just wondering if you can tell me how I can pass particular class name or test case name to run just single test rather than everything.

Comment: @HelpingHands I updated my answer with the link to the command line tools help on MSDN.  On a side note, since we are using Jenkins for the auto build, and launching the tests, we retest everything, not individual tests to ensure none of the changes have broken any tests, not just a specific library.  But the command line is there to do individual tests if you like.